# web service call returns html

Tags: web-services, ms-access

I am calling web services from within Microsoft Access and getting html that looks like

```
"
```

```
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" href="pfp.asmx?disco"/>

<style type="text/css">

    BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; }
    c
```

Previously this has happened when calling a web service over https and I assumed just calling http would sort this out. It didn't, now Microsoft Access crashes with an out of memory exception. (I have checked and SSL certificate's is find and not expired)

I've tried again and it now works (frustrating!).

Calling the web service from .Net works almost always.

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information for me to help.

Comment: Put the web service URL into your browser and see what the response contains. The web service may not be returning the content that MS Access is expecting.

Comment: I just checked the length of what you posted above and it came out as 214 characters, suspiciously close to 255 characters. Are you storing this in a variable? If so, what's the variable's declaration? I think we need to see the code that follows retrieving the response from the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in web services, you get HTML back when the server returns a fault like error 500 or 404. The reason is that the server returns a page with the error details. Is the above the whole text that you get back from the server, or was there an error pasting to StackOverflow??

Comment: That's the whole text I get from ms-access debugger tool (watching the return string) .

Comment: Do what Jon Cram said - put the URL in the browser and check what the whole page should say. As it is now, it's too hard to figure out what the problem is...